# Code mapping program

Tags: javascript, component-diagram

Is there a program that helps create a map of the code. It doesn't have to as indepth as a flowchart, but more like what functions are being called within a class etc.

I'm not looking to create diagrams, but more of an interactive, where I can click a function and see where it's being used.

To be specific, I'm working on a reactJS project and would like to map out where each component is being called.

I would love for the program to go through my code and create this map automatically. But if not, I'm okay with doing it manually. As in entering it manually.

Comment: I've added the JavaScript tag, since there might be tools (e.g. for C#) that would not help you. If the tag does not fit, please add your programming languages instead.

Answer (score 1):

The classic for this is [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org) + [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org) - it can produce documentation including class diagrams, caller maps and calling maps for you code, in addition to a lot of other documentation, complete with links between pages, etc.

It is:

- Free, gratis
- Cross Platform
- Supports multiple programming languages, *PHP, C/C++/C#, Java, FORTRAN, VHDL*
- Can output pages to HTML, LaTeX, RTF, Man, XML & Docbook formats
- Has lots of diagramming options

Just be sure to select EXTRACT_ALL to include functions, classes & methods that do not have the special doxygen format comments to document them.